# Dice roll them up them Dice

Tags: probability

Diana and Apollo each roll a fair die obtaining a number from 1 to 6. What is the
probability that Diana's number is larger than Apollo's number?

I don't understand this problem should i think of it this way example lets say Apollo rolled a 1 does that mean Diana has a 5/6 chance of rolling a higher number or am I overthinking it. Should I use the nCr equation?

Comment: Look at all $36$ possible throws and see how many meet your criterion.

Comment: $\frac{0+1+2+3+4+5}{36}=\frac5{12}$. Another way to see it is that the probability of Diana being higher is the same as that of Apollo being higher, so if we subtract $\frac16$ from $1$, we get the probability that the rolls are different, so we just half that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the probability is dependent on what Apollo Rolls, we will look at his rolls and then the probability of Diana rolling higher

P() is the probability of

P(Apollo Rolling 1) = $\frac16$, P(Diana Rolling > 1) = $\frac56$, therefore probability of both is $\frac16 * \frac56 = \frac{5}{36}$

P(Apollo Rolling 2) = $\frac16$, P(Diana Rolling > 2) = $\frac46$, therefore probability of both is $\frac16 * \frac46 = \frac{4}{36}$

P(Apollo Rolling 3) = $\frac16$, P(Diana Rolling > 3) = $\frac36$, therefore probability of both is $\frac16 * \frac36 = \frac{3}{36}$

P(Apollo Rolling 4) = $\frac16$, P(Diana Rolling > 4) = $\frac26$, therefore probability of both is $\frac16 * \frac26 = \frac{2}{36}$

P(Apollo Rolling 5) = $\frac16$, P(Diana Rolling > 5) = $\frac16$, therefore probability of both is $\frac16 * \frac16 = \frac{1}{36}$

P(Apollo Rolling 6) = $\frac16$, P(Diana Rolling > 6) = $\frac06$, therefore probability of both is $\frac16 * \frac06 = 0$

Now since any of these probabilities can be the solutions we take the sum  to get the change probability of any of these happening $$\frac{5}{36} + \frac{4}{36} + \frac{3}{36} + \frac{2}{36} + \frac{1}{36} + 0 = \frac{15}{36}$$

There you go P(Diana rolling bigger then Apollo)=$\frac{15}{36}$

EDIT:
A more visual way would be to make a tree starting the what Apollo can roll, then branches of what Diana can roll.

Answer (score 1):

Solve it using the same method as with your previous question: count all the possible outcomes, and then count all the ones where Diana's is higher than Apollo's, and divide the latter number by the former.